# Prevent notification from being show when app is open

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, push-notification, foreground

Lets say my app is open and on foreground(i.e. the user is using it) and I get a notification. I don't want it to show up on the notification center as I want to display a custom notification on my app screen. How do I prevent it from being shown?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` will be called if you receive a notification while your app is already open.  Implement this method in your AppDelegate file to display a customized message regarding the notification.